# How can I use MySQL primary key as variable

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to update a column which contains primary key, such as image

```
Update goods 
Set thumb_image = 'xxx/image/{$goods_id}.jpg'
```

how to make it?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use concat for this:-

```
Update goods Set thumb_image = concat('xxx/image/', goods_id, '.jpg')
```